# ASP.NET MVC5 Identity : Use Identity with full IIS and not IIS Express

Tags: asp.net, iis, asp.net-identity, localdb

I'm doing a web site and I want to use Identity for manage my users accounts. When I configure my WebClient to use IIS express, there is no problem. But, I prefere to use Local IIS, and Identity doesn't work with it. 
Here is the error I have when I want to register or Login : 
provider: SQL Network Interfaces, error: 50 - Local Database Runtime error occurred. Cannot create an automatic instance. See the Windows Application event log for error details.

I know my DB is attached on my application (created when my app where using IIS Express), but may I configure IIS for use it ? But I don't know what I must do.
Ideally, I would like to use Identity with the DB of my application (using SQL Server). What can I do ?

Thank you for helping

Comment: check in IIS if you have `Anonymous Authentication` set to `Enabled`